# IE 9 script error -2147467259

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-9

I see a couple of questions here in reference to this error, but they don't seem to fit my situation.

I have an asp.net web application which only works with IE (lots of quirks mode pages and IE specific javascript).  It works fine with all IE versions up to and including IE 8.  But with IE 9, when I load some of the pages I'm getting an error message that error -2147467259 occurred on the page at Line 1 Char 1.   I can dismiss the error dialog and things work more or less ok, although I'm having some other problems which I'm trying to track down.  I don't know if they're related or not.  Has anyone seen errors like this on IE9 but not IE8 or earlier?

Comment: The description for that error code is "Unspecified error", so you would have to look at anything that gives a clue where the error originated. The location "Line 1 Char 1" suggests that it's a script in an event handler in an HTML element, for example the `onload` event in the `body` tag.

Comment: Good idea.  I put in a debugger breakpoint and stepped through all the global javascript with no problem, but the error occurs sometime after that.  Same with the onload event handler.  Do you know how I could get it to drop into the debugger when the error occurs?

Comment: I have the same problem but for me it shows "do you want to stop script?" it only happens in IE9. did you find any answers ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing specifically for IE, particularly older versions of IE, then your probably need to add a meta-tag to force client browser into compatibility mode.  Try adding the following meta-tag:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

Comment: Sounded good, but didn't help unfortunately.  But then again, the application is working fine with IE8 - its just IE9 that's giving me the problem.